# What's the purpose of using require.resolve in Webpack config rules?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

So I was checking the webpack config file generated by create-react-app, when I noticed that when specifying the loaders to use, it uses `require.resolve()`:

[image]

Before I always put the loader name directly like this:
[image]

According to the documentation `require.resolve()` gets the id and compiles it to the path of the module. But still, I'm not sure what exactly is the difference between these two approaches, since they both work. Is it because CRP wraps the config files in a single folder so it is required to resolve the path of the module? Or are there any other reasons?

Comment: I also want to know this.. any news?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This approach is used in CRP since v1.0.0. See [the PR](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/2166) for example. I don't think you should care about it until you build a project with subprojects.

It does make sense when you have a complex project. If you specify a loader using string name, it will be resolved related to the root project. But when you specify it using `require.resolve` it will be resolved related to the config, not to the root application.

```
root
├─┬ project1
│ ├─┬ node_modules
│ │ ╰── awesome-typescript-loader
│ ╰── webpack.config.js
├─┬ project2
│ ├── node_modules
│ ╰── webpack.config.js
├── node_modules
╰── webpack.config.js
```

*root/webpack.config.js:*

```js
module.exports = [
  require('./project1/webpack.config.js'),
  require('./project2/webpack.config.js'),
];
```

In the example above awesome-typescript-loader is only installed for project1. So let's run `webpack` from the root project.

*root/project1/webpack.config.js:*

```js
// It throws "Can't resolve 'awesome-typescript-loader'" error
loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
```

```js
// It works
loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader')
```

Comment: Thanks for an explanation. For the sake of completeness, it would be great to have an example of how the resolution would work differently depending on the method used: require.resolve vs the string. I'm anyway awarding the reputation bonus to this  answer, but if you got some time to add these details, it would be great for future readers.